# Browserify not traversing dependencies in react app (in Gulp)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp, browserify

Im using gulp with browserify and the reactify transform to convert a react jsx into something that the browser can run, but browserify is only turning my main.jsx file into a js file. It doesnt seem to be including the dependencies.

My directory structure is:

```
src
--js
----main.jsx
----components
------app.jsx
------hello.jsx
--index.html
```

In the directory structure above, I've labeled the jsx files with .jsx. Technically, they are currently labeled .js. Hence the use of .js instead of .jsx in the gulpfile. I have changed it to .jsx for the purpose of clarifying that they are .jsx files.

My gulpfile.js is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var reactify = require('reactify');

var path = {
  HTML: 'src/index.html',
  OUT: 'build.js',
  DEST: 'dist',
  DEST_SRC: 'dist/src',
  ENTRY_POINT: './src/js/main.js'
};

gulp.task('copy', function(){
  gulp.src(path.HTML)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(path.HTML, ['copy']);

  var watcher  = watchify(browserify({
    entries: [path.ENTRY_POINT],
    transform: [reactify],
    debug: true,
    cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true
  }));

  return watcher.on('update', function () {
    watcher.bundle()
      .pipe(source(path.OUT))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST_SRC))
      console.log('Updated');
  })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(path.OUT))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.DEST_SRC));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

However, in my dist folder I only have one index.html and one main.js file with the main.js file being:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');

var App = require('./components/app.js');

React.render(
  React.createElement(App, null),
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Which looks like a JSX->JS transformed file without the browserify dependency resolution.

I'm new to node, browserify, and react so this might be a problem of not understanding how it all pieces together in the browser or what each component does.

Comment: Should `require('./components/app.js')` be `require('./components/app.jsx')` (extension mismatch)?

Comment: It is a js extension in my directory. I put a jsx extension in my post to clarify that it is actually a jsx file. Sorry for the inconsistency but I don't think that's the issue here.